# Polling every 10 seonds

Tags: jquery, polling

In the code below, I had the expectation that this would create a polling loop that would fire off every 10 seconds to get a "job status report" from the server. It seems it is creating over 100 calls per second.

I got my education from this excellent **[article](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)**, but I seem to be misreading it.

```
function UpdateEstimates() {
var request = { jobID: ExportVM.get("ticketID") };
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: AppGlobals.serverURL + "GetJobStatus",
    data: request,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    complete: UpdateEstimates,
    timeout: 10000,
    dataType: "json"
});
jqxhr.done(function (data) { NewEstimates(data); });
jqxhr.fail(function (data) { alert('new estimates request failed'); });
```

}

The call is very low overhead, so I can handle easily 1 second updates, but I really don't like the continuous 100/sec rate very much. Is there some way to introduce a delay into the call loop?

Comment: well you are calling the function again right when it completes - I think you have a misunderstanding of `timeout` is

Comment: `timeout` does not delay the call; it simply sets the maximum time the request can take. I would use `setTimeout(UpdateEstimates, 10000)` inside `done()`.

Comment: This is not what is meant by long polling.  You are just trying to poll at a regular interval.  Long polling involves opening a request against the server and the server holding that request open until data is available to return to the client. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the opening and closing of the TCP connection. Which is why I looked at long polling. The article that I references said "This means our poll function won't get called again until both the ajax call is complete and (at-least) thirty (30) seconds have passed." So I had a false understanding of timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timeout in $.ajax is not doing what you actually think. It just sets the timeout for that particular call (maximum allowed time).
You will have to wrap this in setTimeout function.

Comment: Or optionally use `setInterval()`.

Comment: `setInterval()` would fire every 10 seconds (or whatever it is set for). So if your calls are taking more than 10 seconds, you may have overlapping requests, and even possibly out-of-order responses. I'm not saying don't use it, but just understand that it would give you different results.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to not have to tear down and open the TCP connection each time. But I guess that is why polling is not good. Unfortunately, WebSockets is not yet useful for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to re-trigger the timeout on the 'complete' hook.
In this fashion you prevent overlapping reqs.

Tear the 'timeout' param off - as @tomca32 explained timeout is about a req that would take too long.

It would be something like:

```
function UpdateEstimates() {
var request = { jobID: ExportVM.get("ticketID") };
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: AppGlobals.serverURL + "GetJobStatus",
    data: request,
    complete: scheduleUpdEstimates,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
jqxhr.done(function (data) { NewEstimates(data); });
jqxhr.fail(function (data) { alert('new estimates request failed'); });


function scheduleUpdEstimates(){
    setTimeout(function(){ UpdateEstimates(); }, 10000);
}
```