# At startup, run AJAX request every 10 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is in response to the SO problem found here -> [Polling every 10 seonds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364928/polling-every-10-seonds)

That SO post helped, but when I tried to conform it to my needs it just wasn't working out.

I have a php script that will input random data into my database. The script works fine when i point my browser directly to 'create_new_job.php'. My problem is that I cannot seem to run an ajax request to run the script every 10 seconds once my main page loads.

My php script to insert data into database:  'create_new_job.php'

My main page: index.php

This is in my index.php:

```
<script>
    function newjobs() {
    var inputjob = $.ajax({
                    url: "create_new_job.php",
                    complete: schedulenewjobs
                    });
    inputjob.done(function(data) { alert('Job added!'); }
    inputjob.fail(function(data) { alert('Job not added....'); }
}

function schedulenewjobs() {
    setTimeout(function() { newjobs(); }, 10000);
}
</script>
```

First, I'm getting an error at line

`inputjob.fail(.....`

But when I remove the 'done' and 'fail' notices, nothing happens. No data is inserted and I'm not receiving any errors.

I'm not trying to retrieve any data - I'm only wanting to run 'create_new_job.php' every 10 seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not properly closing your functions, and to run the function every ten seconds, you could make it recursive, calling it again from the `done()` callback, or you could use an interval

```
(function newjobs() {
    var inputjob = $.ajax({
                        url: "create_new_job.php"
                   });
    inputjob.done(function(data) {  
        alert('Job added!'); 
        setTimeout(newjobs, 10000); // recursion
    });
//   ^^ missing closing

    inputjob.fail(function() { 
        alert('Job not added....'); 
    });
})();
```

Comment: I think you need to remove `complete: schedulenewjobs`.

Comment: I copy/pasted this but I'm getting an error at the first line. It doesn't like the curly bracket '{'.

Comment: extra or missplaced `(` on first line or something

Comment: Oops, placed the parenthesis in the wrong place there !

Comment: Awesome. Works great now! Thank you! I hate semicolons!

Answer (score 4):

I think this post will help you: **[Send AJAX request every n seconds using jQuery](https://www.codespeedy.com/send-ajax-request-every-n-seconds-using-jquery/)**

```
sendRequest();

 function sendRequest(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "example.php",
    success: 
      function(data){
       $('#listposts').html(data); 
    },
    complete: function() {
   setInterval(sendRequest, 10000); // Call AJAX every 10 seconds
  }
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(
    newjobs(),
    10000
  );
});

function newjobs() {
  inputjob = $.ajax({
    url: "create_new_job.php",
  })
    .done(function(data) { alert('Job added!'); })
    .fail( function(data) { alert('Job not added....'); });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try setInterval function

```
setInterval(function() {
    function newjobs() {
    var inputjob = $.ajax({
                    url: "create_new_job.php",
                    complete: schedulenewjobs
                    });
    inputjob.done(function(data) { alert('Job added!'); }
    inputjob.fail(function(data) { alert('Job not added....'); }
}
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the general syntax errors that were causing the OP's code not to run.  Also, probably much better to start the next Ajax call upon the completion of the previous one rather than entertain the possibility of them getting bogged down and backed up with `setInterval()`.